# CollectionFS S3 ERROR STREAM images Access Denied

Tags: meteor, amazon-s3, collectionfs

I'm trying to set up CollectionFS and S3 so that I can upload files to S3 from AutoForm.

I have an Images FS.Collection defined with a `.allow` function living on the server, like so:

```
// Client and server.
var imageStore = new FS.Store.S3('images', {                                                                            
  region: 'us-east-1',                                                                                                  
  accessKeyId: 'mykey',                                                                                                                                            
  secretAccessKey: 'my/key',                                                          
  bucket: 'buketz',                                                                                               
  folder: 'images',                                                                                                     
});                                                                                                                     

Images = new FS.Collection('images', {                                                                                  
  stores: [imageStore],                                                                                                 
  filter: {                                                                                                             
    allow: {                                                                                                            
      contentTypes: ['image/*'],                                                                                        
      extensions: ['png', 'PNG', 'jpg', 'JPG', 'jpeg', 'JPEG']                                                          
    }                                                                                                                   
  }                                                                                                                     
});

// Server only.
Images.allow({                                                                                                                                                                    
  insert: function (userId, image) {                                                                                    
    return true;                                                                                                        
  },                                                                                                                    
  update: function (userId, image) {                                                                                    
    return true;                                                                                                        
  },                                                                                                                    
  remove: function (userId, image) {                                                                                    
    return true;                                                                                                        
  },                                                                                                                    
  download: function (userId, image) {                                                                                  
    return true;                                                                                                        
  }                                                                                                                     
});
```

Now, when I load the application, Meteor throws me this error:

```
/Users/pcoffey/.meteor/packages/cfs_s3/.0.1.3.1ba5bia++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:32
          throw err;
                ^
Error: Error storing file to the images store: Access Denied
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (packages/cfs:collection/common.js:88:1)
    at [object Object].emit (events.js:106:17)
    at Writable.<anonymous> (packages/cfs:storage-adapter/storageAdapter.server.js:212:1)
    at Writable.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at Response.<anonymous> (packages/cfs:s3/s3.upload.stream2.js:178:1)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/pcoffey/.meteor/packages/cfs_s3/.0.1.3.1ba5bia++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:350:18)
    at Request.callListeners (/Users/pcoffey/.meteor/packages/cfs_s3/.0.1.3.1ba5bia++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:100:18)
    at Request.emit (/Users/pcoffey/.meteor/packages/cfs_s3/.0.1.3.1ba5bia++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
    at Request.emit (/Users/pcoffey/.meteor/packages/cfs_s3/.0.1.3.1ba5bia++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:604:14)
    at Request.transition (/Users/pcoffey/.meteor/packages/cfs_s3/.0.1.3.1ba5bia++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:21:12)
Exited with code: 8
```

Setting `FS.debug` to `true` returns this error:

```
FileWorker ADDED - calling saveCopy images for o5pjjrGD9AfHJwHZG
saving to store images
createWriteStream images, internal: false
createWriteStreamForFileKey images
Meteor._wrapAsync has been renamed to Meteor.wrapAsync
TempStore is mounted on storage.gridfs
FS.TempStore creating read stream for o5pjjrGD9AfHJwHZG
createReadStream _tempstore
createReadStreamForFileKey _tempstore
GRIDFS { _id: 5584b2140cac49f4312c1425, root: 'cfs_gridfs._tempstore' }
FS.HTTP.unmount:
{}
Registered HTTP method URLs:
/cfs/files/:collectionName/:id/:filename
/cfs/files/:collectionName/:id
/cfs/files/:collectionName
=> Meteor server restarted
-----------ERROR STREAM images Access Denied
-----------ERROR STREAM images Access Denied
```

If I change the collection name, it temporarily will load but as soon as I attempt to do a file upload, the error starts up again. Does anyone have ideas as to what may be causing this problem?

Comment: I know it might not be helpful but did you try slingshot meteor package(https://github.com/CulturalMe/meteor-slingshot)? This is by design superior to CFS since it does not pipe the files using the server, but allows you to send it directly to AWS, without disclosing your secrets. However, it wont solve your AWS permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a problem with the AWS permissions. Did you do the [setup](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS/blob/master/packages/s3/README.md#s3-setup)?

Comment: I did do the setup, but perhaps I missed something.

Answer (score 0):

I got setup like this which works very nicely for me. I use following packages:

```
 cfs:standard-packages
 cfs:filesystem
 cfs:s3
 cfs:graphicsmagick
```

//Client side code

```
var companyLogoStore = new FS.Store.S3( "companyLogo" );
Images = new FS.Collection( "images", {
  stores: [ companyLogoStore ],
  filter: {
    maxSize: 5242880, // in bytes
    allow: {
        contentTypes: [ 'image/*' ],
        extensions: [ 'png', 'bmp', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'webp', 'jpg' ]
    }
  },
  onInvalid: function ( message ) {
    if ( Meteor.isClient ) {
        Alerts.add( message, 'danger' );
    } else {
        console.log( message );
    }
  }
} );
```

//Server side code

```
 var companyLogoStore = new FS.Store.S3("companyLogo", {
  region: "xxxxxx", 
  accessKeyId: "xxxxxxx",
  secretAccessKey: "xxxxxxxx",
  bucket: "xxxxxxx",
  ACL: "public-read", **//optional, default is 'private', but you can allow public or secure access routed through your app URL**
  fileKeyMaker: function (fileObj) {
    return 'uploads/company/' + fileObj.original.name;
  },
  transformWrite: function(fileObj, readStream, writeStream) {
    gm(readStream, fileObj.name()).resize('210', '210').stream().pipe(writeStream);
  },
  maxTries: 3 //optional, default 5
 });
```

Also I use ongoworks:security package for permissions

```
Images.files.permit(['insert','update','remove']).ifHasRole(['admin', 'manager']).apply();
```